# iPhone ePub Reader Change font of all pages in ePub book not current webview contents

Tags: iphone, ios, webview

I am developing iphone app like ibook app.I load the contents of `XML` file that I get after parsing the epub file in `UIWebView`.I changed the font size & font family of contents of `UIWebView`.I want to change the font size & font family of all the pages in ePub book.How to store the settings of `UIWebView` so that it is applied to all pages in EPub book.
here is the code how I change the font of weview .

```
NSString *yourHTMLSourceCodeString = [App_delegate.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];

[App_delegate.webView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div style=' font-family:Times New Roman;'>%@",yourHTMLSourceCodeString] baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this project https://github.com/fedefrappi/AePubReader . You can simply store fontName and fontSize values in NSUserDefaults and add CSS rules in webView delegate method webViewDidFinishLoad:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView{

    NSString *fontName = [[NSUserDefault standartUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"fontName"];
    NSNumber *currentTextSize = [[NSUserDefault standartUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"currentTextSize"];

    NSString *varMySheet = @"var mySheet = document.styleSheets[0];";

    NSString *addCSSRule =  @"function addCSSRule(selector, newRule) {"
    "if (mySheet.addRule) {"
    "mySheet.addRule(selector, newRule);"                               // For Internet Explorer
    "} else {"
    "ruleIndex = mySheet.cssRules.length;"
    "mySheet.insertRule(selector + '{' + newRule + ';}', ruleIndex);"   // For Firefox, Chrome, etc.
    "}"
    "}";


    NSString *setTextSizeRule = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('body', '-webkit-text-size-adjust: %d%%;')", [currentTextSize floatValue]];
    NSString *setFont = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('body', 'font-family:%@;')", fontName];


    [theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:varMySheet];

    [theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:addCSSRule];

    [theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:setTextSizeRule];

    [theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:setFont];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the project name "AePubReader". That helped me lots.

Answer (score 0):

Although the post is too old, and above answer helped me a lot, but i faced issues while doing this in **Swift**. So, may be this answer can save someone's time.

```
let varMySheet = "var mySheet = document.styleSheets[0];"

let addCSSRule = "function addCSSRule(selector, newRule) {if (mySheet.addRule) {mySheet.addRule(selector, newRule);} else { ruleIndex = mySheet.cssRules.length;mySheet.insertRule(selector + '{' + newRule + ';}', ruleIndex);}}"

let setTextSizeRule = "addCSSRule('body', '-webkit-text-size-adjust: \(fontPercentage)%;')"


self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(varMySheet)
self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(addCSSRule)
self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(setTextSizeRule)
```

**fontPercentage** is a variable in my class. Default value is 100 and you can increase/decrease that.

For simply updating the fontSize, i'm using "**-webkit-text-size-adjust**" property. and the following piece of code is enough for that:

```
let textSizeRule = "document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '\(fontPercentage)%'"
self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(textSizeRule)
```